# How to change desktop background of a specific user in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch, desktop-customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Schedule Windows XP wallpaper change without additional apps](https://superuser.com/questions/57140/schedule-windows-xp-wallpaper-change-without-additional-apps)
>    I think this is not a duplicate because I asked how to change the background of a different user not the current one logged on. I already know how to do that. Please vote to reopen my question.

I was wondering how to change the desktop background of a specific user. I understand that you have to look into `HKEY_USERS` but I don't know where to go from there. I need to do this in a batch file too. This is for windows xp.

Comment: This link may help you about all. http://superuser.com/questions/57140/schedule-windows-xp-wallpaper-change-without-additional-apps Best Regards

Comment: Thanks :) That does help too :) and I don't think my question is a duplicate... It has a difference in that I want to change the background of a user that is not currently logged on. Just saying :)

Comment: I agree, this isn't an exact duplicate. I've voted to re-open the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with PowerShell:

```
$user = Get-WMIObject -Query "select * from Win32_UserAccount where Name='<username>'"
$path = 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\' + $user.SID + '\Control Panel\Desktop\'
Set-ItemProperty -path $path -name Wallpaper -value 'C:\path\to\wallpaper.jpg'
rundll32.exe user32.dll UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Explanation:

- The first line gets the given user's information using WMI. Specifically, you need the SID that identifies this user under the `HKEY_USERS` registry hive. For more information, see [Get-WMIObject](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315295.aspx), [Win32_UserAccount class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Querying with WQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- The second line simply builds the path to the correct registry key.
- The third line sets the value of the given entry under the given registry key. See [Set-ItemProperty](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315383.aspx) for more information.
- The fourth line forces a refresh of the wallpaper. This is only needed if the specified user is logged in and you need the change to take effect immediately.

Comment: Cheers man :) just what I needed!